# Scala bitwise operation

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation

I am defining a simple function to do some bitwise operation :

```
def getBit(num:Int, i:Int):Boolean = (num & (1 << i) != 0)
```

But I am getting this error :

```
    <console>:7: error: overloaded method value & with alternatives:
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)
       def getBit(num:Int, i:Int):Boolean = (num & (1 << i) != 0)
```

Why I cannot use the `&` operator ? How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should work:
`def getBit(num:Int, i:Int):Boolean = ((num & (1 << i)) != 0)`

Comment: In your example the function `&` gets the result of `(1 << i) != 0` passed as parameter, which is a `Boolean`. The `&` function requires in this case an `Int`.

Answer (score 5):

The operator & has the same precedence as &&, and | has the same precedence as ||, so your expression was evaluated in a different order than you intended.  See section 6.12.3 of [the Scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

The precedence of & and | is non-intuitively low, and a frequent source of errors.  A good working habit is to always parenthesize around them.

Answer (score 0):

You get rid of the problem, if you place the comparison part "0 !=" in the front:

```
def getBit (num: Int, i: Int): Boolean = (0 != (num & (1 << i)))
```

Of course the real reason is the additional parenthesis, like in the other suggested answers. This will not compile, too:

```
def getBit (num: Int, i: Int): Boolean = (0 != num & (1 << i))
```

But the "0 !=" in front might encourage the setting of an additional pair of parens.